End flow with human scalation with Twilio Flow
I am trying to end the interaction in my Dialogflow CX agent with the transition "End Flow With Human Escalation," as shown in the screenshot:
flow in DialogflowCX with the "End With Human Scalation transition"
I want to handle this end of the flow in Twilio Flow Studio using the "Live Agent Handoff" transition to send the conversation to Flex. As shown in the screenshot:
flow in Twilio Flow Studio with the "Live Agent Handoff" transition after a "Conect Virtual Agent" widget
During testing, the transition that was activated in Twilio Flow Studio was "Completed," but the expected transition was "Live Agent Handoff." I don't understand what I need to do to activate the expected transition with this end of the flow.
I tried changing the "end flow" transitions in Dialogflow CX to "End Flow With Failure" since the expected transition in Twilio was "Failed," but it still triggered the "Completed" transition.
I tried managing the VirtualAgentStatus variable in Twilio, but it also resulted in "completed."
I also tried editing the payload in the entry fulfillment in Dialogflow, but the outcome was the same.
As additional information, the route to activate the end of the flow in Dialogflow was 1=1, and the integration is working correctly.

You should not use End Flow with human Escalation but rather use live agent handoff custom payload for live agent transfer on Twilio.

By using this method it will trigger the Live Agent Handoff in Twilio Virtual Agent Widget which will in turn allow you to access the parameters passed from Dialogflow CX in the Twilio Studio anywhere using the following syntax.
{{widgets.PruebaCX.VirtualAgentProviderData.AgentHandoffParameters.service_desk_phonenumber}}


Thanks! It works.
If I want to trigger other use cases like "end with failure" what should I do?

Just use the Live Agent handoff with different Values in the payload.
For Example:

Create A Flow Specifcally Name "End with Failure Flow"
Add a Live Agent Payload with parameters/varialbles as you wish.
Now in other DF CX Flows when "End with Failure" is triggered just connect it to the newly created "End with Failure Flow"
{"REASON":"End With Failure","Test":"Parameter 2 Value"}

